# Pythonでのスクレイピングで、syntax error になりました。どう直せばいいかわかりません。

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

スクレイピングで、１枚目の画像にある「オラフの生まれた日」という１文を引っ張ってきたくて、２枚目の画像のように書いたのですが、属性名にハイフンが入っているからかエラーが出てきてしまいます。この、ハイフン入りの属性ごと消して試すと、Nonetype　object has no attribute 'find' と出てきてしまい、修正方法がわかりません。

**実際の画面:**

[image: 実際の画面です]

**Pythonの画面:**

[image: pythonの画面]

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になりそうです。[How to find all elements with a custom html attribute regardless of html tag using Beautiful Soup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31416858/9014308), [Custom attributes in BeautifulSoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55519595/9014308), [Extracting custom "data" tags using BeautifulSoup (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50777076/9014308), [Python/BeautifulSoup - Getting specific attribute in the same tag/element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38188952/9014308)

Comment: 対象のURLを眺めてみると JavaScript でページを生成しているので、Selenium などを使う方が良いかと思います。

Answer (score 3):

SyntaxErrorの行については、class_に入れたい箇所をシングルクォーテーション'で囲めば解消されます。

```
title = moviedetail.find(
'span', class_='"h2 ng-binding", ng-bind="$ctrl.product.Name"')
```

こちらは正規表現について調べてみることをおすすめします。
しかしながら、そのまま実行しても同じエラーが発生します。このmodal-contentは「もっと見る」をクリックしてから現れるものなので、moviedetailの中にはNoneが入ることになります。
BeautifulSoupは静的な構文解析ライブラリなので、動的なページには前出の通りseleniumのsendkeyなどを使ってみることをおすすめします。

こちらが参考になるかもしれません：
[How to send key with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588660/how-to-send-key-with-beautifulsoup#new-answer?newreg=f60e70bca47344b5bdc035c30f21c7a0)